# Laravel 5.5: 'Auto increment' unique field if exists in database

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I have a database table called `short_urls` which has a list of urls and their 'short' path.

The main fields to note are:

```
$table->string('url')->unique();
$table->string('full_path');
```

I wanted to know if there is a way in Laravel 5.5 to automatically add a number to the `url` field if it already exists.

For example, if I was to use a `DatabaseSeeder` to populate the database and create a `ModelFactory` for `ShortUrl`, something like:

```
$factory->define(App\Models\Route::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'url'       => $faker->slug,
        'full_path' => $faker->url
    ]
});
```

And in my `DatabaseSeeder` I did something like:

```
$shortUrl1 = factory(ShortUrl::class)->create([
    'url' => 'my-short-url'
])

$shortUrl2 = factory(ShortUrl::class)->create([
    'url' => 'my-short-url'
])
```

I want to know if there was a way to ensure that when the second `ShortUrl` that gets created (`$shortUrl2`)...

...It can automatically detect that if a record in the database already exists with the `url` it is trying to set...

...Then it should set it to something like `url => 'my-short-url-2'`

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's entirely doable. Here's an example: https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable/blob/master/README.md#unique

Comment: @btl thanks, i'll give this a go!

Comment: Another way is by [model events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#events). Listen for `creating` and set the value needed. Personally mutators are a much better solution, imo.

Comment: @btl i also like this solution as it keeps everything clean, but i feel as if it may be a bit overkill for what i'm trying to do, but good solution though

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is enforce a check before inserting the url into database, so that we can know if the url is a duplicate or not then append a number accordingly, here is a sample

Then from the controller you can call

```
    private function getUniqueUrl($url)
    {
        $slug = str_slug(trim($url), '-');

        $existingCount = Url::where('url', 'like', $slug . '-%')->count();

        if($existingCount)
        {
          return $slug . '-' . ($existingCount);
        }

        return $slug
    }
```

use the `$slug` to insert into database;

Comment: is there a way to automatically do this on create / update of the model, so that i won't have to do the check and it just does it for me?

Comment: Yeah, add a [mutator method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator) on your model.

Comment: you can override the `create` method from the model, then inject this code there, but this is a much straightforward approach i think

Comment: @btl thanks! i'll try that if I don't succeed with the first comment

Comment: Don't override the create method, that's what mutators are for.

Comment: @btl okay thanks, i'll create a `setUrlAttribute` instead

Comment: thanks @btl seems a very good suggestion, I myself didn't knew about it, https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators

Answer (score 0):

For a new version of Laravel (9) I had a similar issue and I was able to solve it by using an [Observer](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#observers).

Here is my observer code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Observers;

use App\UploadedFile;

class UploadedFileObserver
{
    /**
     * Handle the UploadedFile "creating" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\UploadedFile  $uploadedFile
     * @return void
     */
    public function creating(UploadedFile $uploadedFile)
    {
        // Check if filename exists
        // If it exists, append a number to the end of the filename
        // If that also exists, increment the number by 1 until one is found that does not exist

        $new = $uploadedFile->original_filename;
        $exists = UploadedFile::where('original_filename', $new)->first();
        $count = 1;

        while ($exists) {
            $name      = pathinfo($uploadedFile->original_filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $extension = pathinfo($uploadedFile->original_filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $new       = $name . $count . '.' . $extension;
            $exists    = UploadedFile::where('original_filename', $new)->first();
            $count++;
        }

        $uploadedFile->original_filename = $new;
    }
```

Don't forget to register your Observer in `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`

```
UploadedFile::observe(UploadedFileObserver::class);
```